# React Moment local Timezone

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, utc

I have a UTC date that needs to display the local time. The result of the code below shows the time as 9:30 PM UTC but this isn't what I want. If I add the prop: tz="America/New_York" the time converts properly, but it needs to change based on where the user is. I checked the docs but didn't see a way to add the tz prop without setting an exact location.

```
       <Moment
        format="M/D/YYYY- h:mm A z"
        utc
       >
         2018-12-06T21:30
        </Moment>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can also not see any documented support for determining the user's location/timezone in the `react-moment` library. You will likely need another library to determine that, perhaps one such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/jstz.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the local attribute

```
   <Moment
    format="M/D/YYYY- h:mm A z"
    utc
    local
   >
     2018-12-06T21:30
    </Moment>
```

Documentation in the library:
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/

And in the react-moment 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment#local

In the react-moment documentation I can't see the utc attribute.

When you put the 'utc' you are saying that the date is utc and with the attribute 'local' you call the function local of the library and that transforms the date in a local date in the timezone of the browser

For default the date is in the timezone of the browser, for that reason you have to say that the date is 'utc'. If you call 'local' without the utc it returns the same date.